# Get all followers of a feed

Tags: java, getstream-io

From my understanding, we can use the following API to get all the followers of a feed:

```
List<FeedFollow> followersPaged = feed.getFollowers(filter);
```

It supports passing in a FeedFilter, where the `limit` parameter has a maximum value of `100` and `offset` has a maximum value of `400`.

Does that mean that if a feed is followed by more than 500 feeds, I can only get the first 500 followers (max `offset` of `400` with max `limit` of `100`)?

Is there a way to get all the followers of a feed that has more than 500 followers?

Additionally, is there is a way to check if a specific feed is following another feed? For example, if feed A has 600 followers and feed B is following 600 feeds, is there a way to check if feed B is following feed A?

Comment: [*The resource is limited to the most recent 500 results.*](https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#followers)

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your understanding that the API only allows up to 500 followers to be retrieved.

In addition to REST interface documentation referenced by @shmosel, you 
may like to check the relevant section on [Reading Feed Followers](https://getstream.io/docs/java/#reading-feed-followers) in the Java documentation.

At this point there is no way to retrieve the full set of followers via the API.

To your second question, although the result set is limited to 500 feeds, it is possible to check if a set of specific feeds follow a given feed. See the `filter` parameter in the [Reading Followed Feeds](https://getstream.io/docs/java/#reading-followed-feeds) section of the docs.

Comment: I did look at the `filter` parameter, which is the `FeedFilter` class. There doesn't seem to be a way to build a `filter` with a list of `feedIds` using the `FeedFilter.Builder`. Maybe that's just a bug in their Java client.

Comment: I've raised a PR to resolve this: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-java/pull/31